# Walker_Category - Apply Class To Parent Category Items

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

The code below adds a custom class to all lis items.

How can this be adapted to add a custom class to list items that are parent category items?

I am not entirely sure how to check if a category is a parent in this context.

```
class Cat_Walker extends Walker_Category {
function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        extract($args);

        $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
        $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
        $link = '<a href="' . esc_attr( get_term_link($category) ) . '" ';
        $link .= 'data-filter="' . urldecode($category->slug) . '" ';
        if ( $use_desc_for_title == 0 || empty($category->description) )
                $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__( 'View all posts filed under %s', 'framework' ), $cat_name) ) . '"';
        else
                $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( strip_tags( apply_filters( 'category_description', $category->description, $category ) ) ) . '"';
        $link .= '>';
        $link .= $cat_name . '</a>';

        if ( !empty($feed_image) || !empty($feed) ) {
                $link .= ' ';

                if ( empty($feed_image) )
                        $link .= '(';

                $link .= '<a href="' . get_term_feed_link( $category->term_id, $category->taxonomy, $feed_type ) . '"';

                if ( empty($feed) ) {
                        $alt = ' alt="' . sprintf(__( 'Feed for all posts filed under %s', 'framework' ), $cat_name ) . '"';
                } else {
                        $title = ' title="' . $feed . '"';
                        $alt = ' alt="' . $feed . '"';
                        $name = $feed;
                        $link .= $title;
                }

                $link .= '>';

                if ( empty($feed_image) )
                        $link .= $name;
                else
                        $link .= "<img src='$feed_image'$alt$title" . ' />';

                $link .= '</a>';

                if ( empty($feed_image) )
                        $link .= ')';
        }

        if ( !empty($show_count) )
                $link .= ' (' . intval($category->count) . ')';

        if ( !empty($show_date) )
                $link .= ' ' . gmdate('Y-m-d', $category->last_update_timestamp);

        if ( 'list' == $args['style'] ) {
                $output .= "\t<li";
                $class = 'cat-item cat-item-' . $category->term_id;

                if ( $category->term_id == $category->parent ) {
                    $class .=  ' true';
                } else {
                    $class .=  ' false';
                }

                if ( !empty($current_category) ) {
                        $_current_category = get_term( $current_category, $category->taxonomy );
                        if ( $category->term_id == $current_category )
                                $class .=  ' current-cat';
                        elseif ( $category->term_id == $_current_category->parent )
                                $class .=  ' current-cat-parent';
                }
                $output .=  ' class="' . $class . '"';
                $output .= ">$link\n";
        } else {
                $output .= "\t$link<br />\n";
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought to print_r($args) which actually contained 'has_children => 1'.

Ex:

```
if ( 'list' == $args['has_children'] ) {
    $class .=  ' has-children';
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_category_parents()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents) to determine whether or not a given category has a parent. If it doesn't, a [WP_Error](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) will be returned. You can verify whether or not there was an error with [is_wp_error()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error).

You posted way too much code, so I'll just outline how this should be used, rather than write a whole new file for you:

```
<?php

    $parents = get_category_parents( $category->term_id );

    // If it doesn't have a parent (i.e. it IS a parent)...
    if ( is_wp_error( $parents ) ) {
        // Add a class
    }

?>
```

Comment: Ideally I wanted it to work with Walker_Category. I posted that chunk as reference, but agreed it looks ghastly.